# `not found in location` error when querying external table with Google Cloud Storage as source

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I'm working on a DBT project where:

- Location is defined in the `profiles.yml` file
- Data source are defined in `sources.yml` file
- The data source generating the error is a BigQuery table created with GCS as data source as External Tables.

When running a query based on this source I have the following error `not found in location`

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question. What I found is that I only had the error when the Source URI was a direct selection of a file in the cloud storage folder. When I was using `*` with the root folder of my bucket storage I didn't had the error. To summarise:

External Data Configuration Source URI =>  `gs://hubspot_bucket/*` => no error in DBT

External Data Configuration Source URI =>  `gs://hubspot_bucket/folder/file` => `not found in location` error